# Is it possible to check what a PHP script is doing when it's already running?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that has been running for a week, as it's doing a lot of number crunching -- it's not hung, just doing a lot of work. Problem is that I don't know where it has got to and so I don't know if it will finish in 1 hour or 1 month. (Yes, I should have put something in there so that it tell me, but too late for that now.)

Is there any way I can find out what the script is doing? Or even better, to extract variables from its current state?

Comment: "number crunching" "PHP" and "has been running for a week" doesn't make me feel good.

Comment: Is it doing any file writes / database writes you could look for?

Comment: I agree: any other language would have been better, but I program best in PHP... so it just made sense. Time saved overall.

Comment: It was doing file writes for the first section to tell me what it was doing, but for the latter section I expected it to not take so long, so I didn't think to made it output what it was doing. It is taking a long time though.

Comment: Is the memory consumption giving any clues?

Comment: "I don't know if it will finish in 1 hour or 1 month ... I expected it to not take so long" --- ow

Comment: @webnoob that would be a clue, except that PHP doesn't free variables that have been unset until it needs to. So the memory used (which is 12GB) has not been changing even though it is unsetting variables as it goes along.

Comment: If your operating system supports this, `strace` or `dtrace` is your friend.

Comment: I think status message will be written manually inside the program. If there is any in build system for tracking any program execution status that time I think it would be like a gold coin to hacker. So putting status message manually , I think is good solution.

Comment: @complex857 great tip, I didn't know about these commands and they proved useful!

Comment: is it cronned, screened, something else? what context is it running? does it output anybstatus you can check

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can check what php.exe is doing with Microsoft's [procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).
It won't give you a full feedback on variables etc, but you can check for any filesystem-operations (which php does very often). PHP has some internal functions stored as extra .exe's. You can check with procmon if PHP call's them...

Comment: OK. I'm on Linux CentOS 6. Anything for that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the script has finished its tasks by now. As a general guide, on Linux, you check what's happening with the processes running on your system, with top command. It gives you a window of all processes running.
To concentrate on a single process you may get its PID (Process ID) by ps command. So you can run:

$ ps -e

This command will give a 4 columns output. The left column is PID while the right one is the script name. Say you find the script name at the right column, and you check that its PID is 3468. Then running

$ top -p 3468

you get the periodically updated top window. You can select different kind of info in there. Usually you check %CPU, and VIRT, first. VIRT column is useful, because if it's constantly increasing, it's an almost definite sign of memory leak in the script.
Alternatively you may use htop and highlight the process you chose, if you have it installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The already suggested answers.. Simply show that a script is running.. This as you already stated is not your need...

As for a script already running that does not log / store any information.. Well the only true option you have that i can think of is checking what it is processing.. So if it is processing files / a database.. You should be able to see the changed / modified results.

If its purely all in memory, your more or less out of luck unless you happen to use something like a session.

But simply checking if the script is running... is of no help at all.., So if its processing a database, check the database, If its processing files, check the files.. Otherwise your out of luck.

When it comes to heavy cruncher scripts, for example when i do geo-coding... I store results / processed data in local files.. So if the script fails or stops.. I can resume.. But the benefit of this is i can run another script and read those files and see the progress or last step performed.

CAN this be resumed or would it start over again? If it can be resumed, stop it and have it log or something so you can monitor it? Otherwise your just going to have to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score -1):

I have written some PHP scripts that take a very long time to run.  Usually I have the script update a database table with some statistics occasionally (ex: if in a loop, every 10000 loops, depending on weight of the loop...also take samples of microtime to see how long a particular step takes).  I can then check the table for the "statistics" to see how the script is performing, or what particular step it is on.

I'd agree with what others have said about PHP not being the best language for this, but in a pinch I've found this method works well (I've had PHP scripts run stable for months).